# Why this conditional subsetting from a csv file returns incorrect answer in R?

Tags: r, csv, import, subset

Suppose I have the following data called `D` (*9 columns, 395 rows*):

```
D = read.csv("https://docs.google.com/uc?id=0B5V8AyEFBTmXQ1QwWVZuS3FXOHc&export=download")
```

In `D`, when I try to find out the length of `p.value`s that are less than `.05`, I get an erroneous answer:

```
length(D$p.value <= .05) # Returns "395", which is the total number of rows not those <= .05
```

I'm wondering what the correct code code return the correct length of `p.value`s that are less than `.05` in `D`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
sum(D$p.value <= .05)
```

I believe your problem may be that you are simply counting the size of the comparison vector.  Of course, its size is the same as the data frame.  Instead, my answer counts only entries for which the inequality is actually true.

@RichScriven edit: Summing the inequality will automatically convert the booleans to numbers, either 0 or 1.

Note that if you take a sum of a vector containing even one `NA` value then the resulting sum will also be `NA`.  One option would be to ignore those `NA` values by removing them via:

```
sum(D$p.value <= .05, na.rm = TRUE)
```

Comment: Tim, I wondering if there might be a better (i.e., a bit more intuitive) strategy than using `as.numeric()` here?

Comment: @user138773, I guess the more intuitive way is to use: `length(D$p.value[D$p.value <= .05])`

Comment: Tim, does `sum(D$p.value <= .05)` still return the correct answer? On my machine it returns `NA`

Comment: Use `na.rm = TRUE`, q.v. the updated answer.